# Counting groups of people in age ranges

Tags: c#

I have a little method to get the number of members in a certain age range. The range is supposed to be inclusive in both ends, i.e. if I call `CountSelection(memberList, 16, 19)` (where `memberList` is a `List<Member>`), I expect to get the number of members aged 16, 17, 18 and 19 summed together:

```
private int CountSelection(List<Member> members, int minAge, int maxAge)
{
    DateTime from = DateTime.Now.AddYears(minAge * -1);
    DateTime to = DateTime.Now.AddYears(maxAge * -1);
    return members.Count(m =>
        m.DateBorn.Date <= from.Date && 
        m.DateBorn.Date >= to.Date);
}
```

However, my method is not reliable - sometimes it will omit members, I'm guessing when birth dates fall between ranges. In the main method, I'm calling `CountSelection()` several times, each with different ranges, theoretically covering all ages.

What should the query look like to guarantee that all the members will be counted?

Comment: I think your `from` and `to` dates are swapped.  The way your code is written, the `to` date comes *before* the `from` date, which doesn't seem right.

Comment: You don't need to multiply by -1, you can just negate the expression directly. For example, `DateTime.Now.AddYears(-minAge)` :)

Comment: Age is not the same as year person was born...

Comment: The question is if somebody was born in February 2017 are they two or three year old?  If maxAge = 2 they are not included.  When you have a range the min should be >= while the max should only be <, otherwise you have one extra day.

Comment: Use DateTime.Date.AddYears? DateTime.Now.AddYears includes a time component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why my method was failing. I was just subtracting whole years from the from and to dates, and that resulted in ranges that looked like this (date format dd.mm.yyyy):

```
0-5 years - 11.04.2014-11.04.2019
6-12 years - 11.04.2007-11.04.2013
13-19 years - 11.04.2000-11.04.2006
20-26 years - 11.04.1993-11.04.1999
... and so on.
```

Notice the gap of almost a year between each range.

Solution:

Instead of setting the from-date like this:

```
DateTime from = DateTime.Now.Date.AddYears(-maxAge);
```

I of course have to subtract a further 1 year and add 1 day:

```
DateTime from = DateTime.Now.Date.AddYears(-maxAge + 1).AddDays(1);
```

Now the ranges look like this:

```
0-5 years - 12.04.2013-11.04.2019
6-12 years - 12.04.2006-11.04.2013
13-19 years - 12.04.1999-11.04.2006
20-26 years - 12.04.1992-11.04.1999
... and so on.
```

The final, working method looks like this:

```
private int CountSelection(List<Member> members, int minAge, int maxAge)
{
    DateTime from = compareDate.AddYears(-maxAge+1).AddDays(1);
    DateTime to = compareDate.AddYears(-minAge);
    return members.Count(m => 
        m.DateBorn >= from && 
        m.DateBorn <= to);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to work with ranges with exclusive upper bounds:

```
private int CountSelection(List<Member> members, int minAge, int maxAgeExclusive)
{
    DateTime from = compareDate.AddYears(-maxAgeExclusive);
    DateTime to = compareDate.AddYears(-minAge);
    return members.Count(m => m.DateBorn > from && m.DateBorn <= to);
}
```

Now your ranges will be mathematically more consistent.

```
0-6 years
6-13 years
13-20 years
20-27 years
etc
```

Then you can subtract one from the upper limit at the presentation layer.